# killed a process, it comes back

Tags: process, kill

I have some process running

```
>ps | grep camera
 2345  root  3.08  someprocess camera.json
```

I am trying to kill it but neither

```
kill 2345
kill -9 2345
```

work. The process comes back to life under a different PID

Why is this happening and how can I kill it?

Comment: "The process comes back to life under a different PID", then it clearly worked and the process you tried to kill died, didn't it?

Comment: how can I avoid that it comes back?

Comment: You should rephrase your question, as @muru's comment is clearly correct.

Comment: The process doesn't "come back". Something else is starting it. So, clearly, you need to figure out what that is, and change its behaviour.

Comment: Look at the process tree.  You might need to kill that process's parent; or _that_ process's parent.  A new process replacing the one you just `kill`ed is not the process failing to be killed; it's a watchdog replacing a child that died unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is a service that starts it automatically.

List the services:

```bash
systemctl status
```

Press `/` and insert the process name for searching the name of the service.

You can stop/disable the service:

```bash
sudo systemctl stop <service name>
sudo systemctl disable <service name>
```

Comment: Much simpler if it is a service on a system running systemd: systemctl status PID (with PID the pid OP attempts to kill): it will show only the service it belongs to.